# Dispay images from Paperclip in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I am using Paperclip with multiple picture upload. Uploaded pictures are shown in my @post view:

```
  <% for asset in @post.assets %>
    <%= link_to image_tag(asset.image.url(:thumb)), asset.image.url(:big), :class => "fancybox", :rel => "gallery" if asset.image? %>
  <% end %>
```

my problem is that I want these pictures to show in another view too, like this:

```
  <% for asset in @post.assets %>
    <%= image_tag asset.image.url(:thumb) if asset.image? %>
  <% end %>
```

view controller:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def school_news
    @posts = Post.page(params[:page]).per(4).order('posts.id DESC')
  end
end
```

Now I have this error:

```
 NoMethodError in Home#school_news

Showing D:/Projects/livu_pamatskola/app/views/home/school_news.html.erb where line #17 raised:

undefined method `assets' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #17):

14:             <%= link_to 'Lasīt vairāk...', posts %> 
15:         </div>
16:     </div>
17:   <% for asset in @post.assets %>
18:     <%= image_tag asset.image.url(:thumb) if asset.image? %>
19:   <% end %>
20:     <div id="separator"></div>
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please explain more?

Comment: `@post` is nil. It needs a value in order to call post-ish methods on it. The controller you show sets `@posts`, not `@post`. You're calling `@post.assets`. Where do you set `@post`?